# Android ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo how to get Task full name

Tags: android

I have property `ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo taskinfo`

and now i can get `ClassName` like `taskinfo.baseActivity.getClassName()`

but can i somehow cast it to `ApplicationInfo`.

Why? I would like to get task name like Opera, Youtube,.. and not just class name

IS this possible?

Comment: Have you tried [this method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3861268/752320)?

Comment: I want to use RunningTaskInfo and not RunningAppProcessInfo

Comment: `RunningTaskInfo` simply doesn't contain that data. They're for separate purposes.