# Determining if an Activity exists on the current device

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to know what activity is being displayed in android device

if the activity that I will search I execute code
if not I execute another code

purpose is to make an android service to check this task

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

[Get active Application name in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861073/get-active-application-name-in-android)

Just tweak it with the functionality you want, and you should be able to check rather easily.

Comment: I want to do with the activitéManager what the activity during execution
I want to compare with another activity (exp: MainAlarme)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that's what you want?

> purpose is to make an android service to check this task

If you told us what was the reason behind your "purpose", I'm almost sure we could help you with a better way of doing what you want (probably we could find a way which would waste less battery and which would antagonize less your users).

**In any case, here is the answer to your question:**

Use [getRunningTasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html) of ActivityManager to get a list of the recently launched activities.

> **public
>   List
>   getRunningTasks (int maxNum)**
>
> Return a list of the tasks that are
>   currently running, with the most
>   recent being first and older ones
>   after in order. Note that "running"
>   does not mean any of the task's code
>   is currently loaded or activity -- the
>   task may have been frozen by the
>   system, so that it can be restarted in
>   its previous state when next brought
>   to the foreground.

You might also want to use the flag **`RECENT_WITH_EXCLUDED`** to make sure you get all the activities, even the ones that purposefully exclude themselves from that list.

> `public static final int` **`RECENT_WITH_EXCLUDED`**
>
> Added in API level 1 Flag for use with `getRecentTasks(int, int)`:
>   return all tasks, even those that have set their
>   `FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS` flag.

Comment: I want to do with the activitéManager what the activity during execution
I want to compare with another activity (exp: MainAlarme)

Comment: Activité? Do you speak French by any chance? My own native language is French so I can switch to that language if need be (and translate for the rest of us). Why do you want to compare the activity with MainAlarm? Did you know that the alarm clock had its own Content Provider that you could manipulate the values of? What kind of application are you trying to make?

Answer (score 0):

I found this code it works very well

```
Log.i("---------------", "----------onCreate--------------");

        Log.i("-----test------", "----------1--------------");
         ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this .getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
         Log.i("-----test------", "----------2-------------");
           List<RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
           Log.i("-----test------", "---------3--------------");
            ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
            Log.i("-----test------", "----------4--------------");
            Log.i("------------------", "CURRENT Activity ::" + taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName()+"   Package Name :  "+componentInfo.getPackageName());
            Log.i("-----test------", "----------5--------------");
```