# Name running application and not package name

Tags: java, android, activity-manager

Is possible have only the name of running application and not the package name? I have this code now:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<RunningAppProcessInfo> processes = am.getRunningAppProcesses();

        if (processes != null){
            for (int i=0; i<processes.size(); i++){
                RunningAppProcessInfo temp = processes.get(i);
                String pName = temp.processName;
                Log.d("Running process: ", pName);
            }
        }
```

But it returns the package name like: `com.android.camera`. I need only `camera` or for example `Nova launcher`.

Comment: Check this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861073/get-active-application-name-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
final PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
ApplicationInfo ai;
try {
   ai = pm.getApplicationInfo( this.getPackageName(), 0);
} 
   catch (final NameNotFoundException e) {
   ai = null;
}  
final String applicationName = (String) (ai != null ? pm.getApplicationLabel(ai) : "(unknown)");
```

This would return the application name as defined in  tag of its manifest.