# How to know Specificaly Name of the running apps in android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I get a list of apps which are running on device correctly:

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> services = activityManager.getRunningServices(99);

ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List l = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
```

**But with this I get complete package name like:**

```
com.google.process.location, com.whatsapp
```

**I also used split function**

```
for (String aa1 : risky_arr) {
    String[] splits = aa1.split(" ");
    String aa2 = (splits[1].substring(0, splits[1].length()-1));
    hashSet.add(aa2);           
}
```

But it also shortens the length like I said above.

So my problem is, how can I get only app name like Whatsapp, location, paisa, swipe etc.

Comment: Try this ...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861073/get-active-application-name-in-android

Comment: I'll do the same thing what in your link. It gives complete name

Comment: I want only app name.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to get app name:

```
 ResolveInfo packageInfo = mApps.get(position);
  PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();

  appName = new String(packageInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
```